# Как организовать внутреннюю структуру классов?

Tags: php, laravel, ооп

Доброго времени суток.

- есть система учёта заказов (crm), в ней есть заказы, клиенты, склад,
  прочие прелести.
- есть модели (сущности), каждой таблице в бд соответствует свой одноимённый класс унаследованный от `Model`.
- есть контроллеры для каждой сущности, в них методы для создания, редактирования, удаления, методы для вывода данных (возвращают `View` с наборами данных, все данные берутся с помощью ORM прямо "на месте").

В данной схеме напрашиваются классы для сущностей, что бы к ним был доступ из любого контроллера (например, в контроллере заказа получить объект клиента по его id) (это и так можно сделать, но суть ниже).

Я предполагаю что нужно создать отдельную папку с классами и переносить туда всю логику с сущностями (что бы максимально освободить контроллер оставив там только вызов методов). Но в моделях так же можно создавать методы и работать с ними, а можно создать отдельный класс который моделью являться не будет, он будет в роли прослойки между контроллером и моделью.

**Вопрос вот в чём:** где лучше описывать методы сущностей? Если делать прослойку о которой написал выше, то как грамотно называть классы, ведь имена классов, например, `Clients` уже заняты моделями и какие методы должны быть в этой прослойке, а какие в модели? Либо вообще как то по другому сделать?

**P.S.** Выбрал следующую тактику: сделал классы под названиями classnameService, в них вся бизнес-логика(никаких orm-конструкций), а в них вызываются методы модели которые взаимодействуют с бд. А сами эти классы вызываются из контроллеров

Дополнение для конкурса:

1. Зачем нужны репозитории, если есть модели ?
2. Почему в laravel нет сеттеров-геттеров в традиционном их понимании? (нет методов для возвращения полей, они доступны по `$object->field`, IDE их к выбору не предлагает т.к. они protected, ещё и в массиве)
3. Как организовать цепочную схему, что бы, например, можно было писать вызовы так: `$object->getClient()->checkRegularCustomer()` объединив в них методы моделей (для выборки данных) и сервисов (для бизнес логики)? в данный момент у меня есть модели и сервисы, модели отвечают за взаимодействие с бд (CRUD), а сервисы за бизнес-логику (получить товары по заказу, получить их остаток на складе, etc), но в цепочку можно вернуть только один объект.
4. Как, в общем случае, делится ответственность классов и уровней? пример: есть метод создания клиента. что бы это сделать нужно взять номер телефона и привести к виду "89998887766" удалив всё лишнее что может быть. Это не вопрос валидации, а вопрос нормализации, за это должен отвечать контроллер, сервис или модель?

Comment: Называйте их в соответствии с их ЕДИНОЙ ответственностью. Т.е. всё предельно просто: когда я вижу название класса, я уже должен понять, какую он выполняет работу.

Comment: имена классов моделей изменить нельзя, laravel на их основе работает с таблицами. например класс Clients (extends Model) будет работать с таблицей clients. префиксы указываются отдельно, не в имени класса. а класс как грамотно назвать, CClients?

Comment: Я не про классы-сущности. Их так и нужно называть -- Client.
Я про сервисы. Например, вам нужен сервис, который считает общую сумму заказа. Тогда вы может создать класс, например, с таким названием: OrderPriceCalculator.

Comment: а почему это должен быть именно сервис, а не метод класса-прослойки orders? и если сервис такой "узконаправленный", то где объявлять всё остальное(создание, рекдактирование, выдачу страниц, etc)?

Comment: Потому что это соответствует первому принципу SOLID: Single Responsibily Principle. Каждый класс должен иметь одну ответственность.

Comment: посмотрите на шаблон DataMapper

Comment: Посмотрите цикл статей [Laravel beyound CRUD](https://stitcher.io/blog/laravel-beyond-crud-01-domain-oriented-laravel) - про доменную организацию. Там довольно много: делайте модели и контроллеры тонкими. Например, нужно сменить статус модели "заказ оплачен" - делайте класс "перевод статуса" со всей бизнес-логикой. В контроллере - только получение объекта (модели) и передача в объект "перевод статуса". Также там предлагается более удобная для масштабного проекта файловая организация. Я думаю, почти все вопросы после прочтения отпадут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> зачем нужны репозитории, если есть модели ?

Репозитории отвечают за взаимодействие с уровнем данных(бд в вашем случае). Они обеспечивают инкапсуляцию. Если вам вдруг нужно будет поменять хранилище, вы реализуете другой репозиторий с таким же интерфейсом, который будет ходить в другое хранилище. Это удобно. Ваша бизнес логика ничего не знает о том, где хранятся данные и это хорошо.

Модели - описывают поля одного объекта из коллекции. Ничего другого они делать не должны. Да в laravel легко делать запросы Order::query, но неверно делать их в модели. Это нарушение SRP. Операции с наборами данных из хранилища должны быть в репозиториях.

> почему в laravel нет сеттеров-геттеров в традиционном их понимании?

Странный вопрос, возможно вы имели ввиду, что они не генерируются автоматический? Использование геттеров и сеттеров хорошая практика и я вам рекомендую работать с полями модели именно через них.

> как организовать цепочную схему, что бы, например, можно было писать
> вызовы так: $object->getClient()->checkRegularCustomer()...

Не вижу проблемы. Давайте приведу пример:

```php
class Order
{
    private OrderModel $model;
    private ClientRepository $clientRepository;
    private ClientFactory $clientFactory;

    public function __construct(
        OrderModel $model,
        ClientRepository $clientRepository,
        ClientFactory $clientFactory
    ) {
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->clientRepository = $clientRepository;
        $this->clientFactory = $clientFactory;
    }

    public function getClient(): Client
    {
        $clientModel = $this->clientRepository->getActiveClient($this->model->getId());
        return $this->clientFactory->create($clientModel);
    }
}


class Client
{
    private ClientModel $model;
    public function __construct(OrderModel $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function checkRegularCustomer(): void;
}
```

Классы Order и Client  являются классами доменного уровня, то есть реализуют бизнес логику. При этом они не ходят сами в бд(это делает репозиторий). Модель имеет только геттеры и сеттеры и не содержит никаких запросов и бизнес логики.

> как, в общем случае, делится ответственность классов и уровней?
> пример: есть метод создания клиента. что бы это сделать нужно взять
> номер телефона и привести к виду "89998887766" удалив всё лишнее что
> может быть. это не вопрос валидации, а вопрос нормализации, за это
> должен отвечать контроллер, сервис или модель?

Нет какого то универсального решения для деления, но у каждого класса должна быть своя ответственность.

В данном конкретном примере могу предложить такой вариант:

1. Контроллер принимает запрос и передает управление валидатору.
2. В случае успешной валидации, данные передаются сервису.
3. Сервис сам не содержит бизнес логики, но знает как ее вызвать.
4. Сервис передает управление классу PhoneNormalizer.
5. После успешного выполнения PhoneNormalizer->normilize сервис передает результат работы в метод createClient(в котором через репозиторий происходит сохранение)
6. После успешного выполнения метода createClient сервис возвращает результат контроллеру.

> выбрал следующую тактику: сделал классы под названиями
> classnameService

Да, сервисы могут содержать бизнес логику, но я бы рекомендовал использовать для этого отдельные классы. Не модели, не репозитории, не контроллеры. Просто классы, в которых будет только бизнес логика.

Так же, рекомендовал бы вам делать сервисы исходя их бизнес сущностей, а не моделей.

> Но в моделях так же можно создавать методы и работать с ними, а можно
> создать отдельный класс который моделью являться не будет, он будет в
> роли прослойки между контроллером и моделью.

Лучше создавать отдельный класс, который не будет прослойкой, а будет содержать только бизнес логику без лишних подробностей(не будет знать что такое http запрос, что такое база данных и т д). Частой проблемой является, то что по мере увеличения кодовой базы бизнес логика расползается по всему проекту - это плохо. "Если вы не найдете место бизнес логике, она найдет его сама".

> где лучше описывать методы сущностей?

В отдельных классах если это бизнес логика. В модели только описание полей.

> как грамотно называть классы, ведь имена классов, например, Clients
> уже заняты моделями и какие методы должны быть в этой прослойке, а
> какие в модели?

Они могут называться одинаково, но находится в разных неймспейсах:

```
App\Domain\Client
App\Service\Client
App\Model\Client
App\Repository\Client
```

Но я бы рекомендовал еще и использовать постфиксы:

```
App\Service\ClientService
App\Model\ClientModel
App\Repository\ClientRepository
```

> все данные берутся с помощью ORM прямо "на месте"

Контроллеры - это уровень взаимодействия с пользователем. В них должно быть минимум логики и вообще не должно бизнес логики. В идеале, в методе контроллера, должен быть вызван метод сервиса и все. То есть контроллер знает только кому передать управление.

Итого советую вам:

1. Не писать запросы в моделях, использовать репозитории.
2. Бизнес логику описывать в отдельных классах, доступ к этим классам получать через сервисы.
3. Держать контроллеры "тонкими".

Все эти рекомендации можно не выполнять и проблем не будет если у вас маленький проект. Но если выполнять, то при увеличении кодовой базы у вас не возникнет проблем. Основной плюс соблюдения принципа единой ответственности и разбиение все на классы - это проще тестировать и проще заменять. Если проект активно развивается - бизнес требования меняются часто. Надо делать так чтобы каждое такое изменение требовало минимум трудозатрат в будущем.

Comment: по поводу сеттеров-геттеров, их действительно нет, если их написать, то они будут работать, но IDE скажет что такого поля в классе нет. если объявить их в модели (рядом с protected $fillable), то они просто перезапишут поля модели и будут пустые. это нормальная практика и на статический анализатор IDE в этом случае описаться не стоит?

Comment: Просто добавляйте геттеры и сеттеры, для того чтобы ide не ругалась - используйте doc  блок.  Пример https://pastebin.com/q1yPTKg2

Comment: Не совсем понял, что автор и вы подразумеваете под репозиториями? Отдельные папки с классами? Лайкнул, но могли бы вы привести пример сервиса, который взаимодействует с простой бизнес логикой. + Есть небольшое замечание, проверку данных делать необходимо в `middleware`, а только потом переходить в контроллер. Ведь контроллер это уже часть ядра.

Comment: Под репозиториями имеется ввиду патерн https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/More/Repository/README.html. По поводу валидации в middleware - я не согласен. Middleware нужны не только для валидации. Переводить всю валидацию на middleware неверно. Валидация бывает сложной и связанной с бизнес логикой. Middleware о всем этом знать не должна. Контроллер это уровень взаимодействия с пользователем. Вызывать в контроллере нужный валидатор - нормальное решение.

Comment: Возможно под валидацией в midleware вы имеете ввиду это https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#form-request-validation. Да это форма которая заполняется в middleware. Я бы не стал говорить о том, что так надо делать. Это просто один из подходов в laravel, который упрощает валидацию.

Answer (score 3):

Очень хороший вопрос:

Как найти баланс между реализацией необходимой функциональности по обработке данных между контроллером и моделью?

Исходя из моего опыта разработки подобных систем (а у меня их было много) я могу дать несколько советов (чисто мое субъективное мнение):

1. Добавлять лишние сущности-прослойки это значит усложнять понимание системы. Лучше этого не делать без особой необходимости. Необходимость в таких классах может появиться в случае появления дополнительных требований к системе по обработке данных, например, при необходимости вести какую-то синхронизацию с другими системами или логирование... Но это все равно очень сильно усложняет систему и нужно, по возможности, избегать создание новых сущностей.
2. Обработку данных в модели нужно делать в случае, если эта обработка касается прямого доступа к полям и функциональности доступа к данным. Например, делаются дополнительные SQL запросы к базе при формировании ответа модели контроллеру. Основные критерии помещения функциональности в модель это: производительность, использование внутренней реализации модели и скрытие приватной реализации от контроллера.
3. Обработку данных в контроллере нужно делать в случае обобщенной обработки нескольких моделей или создание дополнительной функциональности по контролю связанных данных в модели. Критерии помещения кода в контроллер: невозможность или сложность объединения нескольких сущностей в модели, дополнительная обработка данных не связанная напрямую с функциональностью модели и обобщение данных модели для отображения.